# AWS add Lambda to SQS Queue programmatically

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, lambda, amazon-sqs

I am creating SQS-Queues programmatically for each of my customers. Now I want to add an already created Lambda trigger to that SQS-Queues. Is this possible, or do I have to add those Lambdas manually by the AWS Console? I didn't find any helpful documentation about that.

Thanks

Comment: **Everything** you can do in the console uses AWS Apis that are available for programmatic access as well. [CreateEventSourceMapping](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/API_CreateEventSourceMapping.html) in your case.

Comment: @luk2302 Nope. You can't make an encrypted S3 object unencrypted in a default-bucket encryption-enabled bucket using APIs.

Comment: Thank you guys! @luk2302 CreateEventSourceMapping  was exactly what I needed! It works now.

Answer (score 0):

You can't add a Lambda to an SQS-Queue, but you can add an SQS-Queue to an existing Lambda. For Example:

```
$lambdaClient = new LambdaClient([
                    'region'      => ***REGION***,
                    'version'     => 'latest',
                    'credentials' => [
                        'key'    => ***KEY***,
                        'secret' => ***SECRET***,
                    ]
                ]);
                
                $createEventSourceMapping = $lambdaClient->createEventSourceMapping([
                    'BatchSize'      => 10,
                    'EventSourceArn' => ***ARN-OF-SQS-QUEUE***,
                    'FunctionName'   => ***FUNCTION NAME OF LAMBDA***
                ]);
```

Comment: *"You can't add a Lambda to an SQS-Queue, but you can add an SQS-Queue"* - yes, because for some services the Lambda service itself implements the polling and subscribing and invoking lambda functions. But for other services, e.g. S3 _that_ service itself needs to trigger lambda.